# Insert OpportunityLineItem - Error

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem, before-trigger, recursion

I am trying to automate the following functionality: When an opportunity stage becomes '`Pending Payment`', insert 2 '`OpportunityLineItems`' using 2 predefined Products.

This is my current code. I am calling the class on an before update event on the `Opportunity` Sobject:

```
public void addProductWhenStageIsPendingPayment() {

        Set<id> ids = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity o : newOpportunities.values()){
            if(o.stagename=='Pending Payment')
                ids.add(o.id);
        }


        List<Opportunity> opps = [Select id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c,CurrencyIsoCode,PriceBook2id from Opportunity where id in: ids];// and  Start_Date__c!=null and  End_Date__c!=null];

        List<Product2> products = [Select id,name, CurrencyIsoCode from Product2];
        Id product1Id=NULL;
        id product2id=NULL;

        list<PriceBookEntry> priceBookList = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Id, Product2.Name FROM PriceBookEntry 
                                             WHERE  PriceBook2.isStandard=true ];
        Id priceBook1Id=NULL;
        id priceBook2id=NULL;

        List<OpportunityLineItem> oppsline = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

        for(Opportunity op : opps)  
        {
            // get the product ids
             for(Product2 p : products)
            {
                if(p.name=='Name A' & p.CurrencyIsoCode==op.CurrencyIsoCode)
                product1Id=p.id;
                if(p.name=='Name B' &   p.CurrencyIsoCode==op.CurrencyIsoCode)
                product2Id=p.id;
             }

            // get the price book ids
            for(PriceBookEntry pbe : priceBookList)
            {
                if(pbe.Product2Id== product1Id)
                    priceBook1id = pbe.id;
                if(pbe.Product2Id == product2Id)
                    priceBook2id = pbe.id;
            }



            Date startDate = op.Start_Date__c;
            Date endDate = op.End_Date__c;
            Integer monthDiff = startDate.monthsBetween(endDate);
            monthDiff++;

            for(integer i=0; i<monthDiff ; i++)
            {
                OpportunityLineItem oli1 = new OpportunityLineItem( PricebookEntryId=  priceBook1Id  , Opportunityid=op.id,UnitPrice=1000,Quantity=22,ServiceDate=endDate,  Description='Name A',Estimate_Actual__c='Estimated');
                OpportunityLineItem oli2 = new OpportunityLineItem( PricebookEntryId=  priceBook2Id , Opportunityid=op.id,UnitPrice=250,Quantity=22,ServiceDate=endDate,    Description='Name B',Estimate_Actual__c='Estimated');
                oppsline.add(oli1);
                oppsline.add(oli2);
            }

        }

        insert oppsline;

    }
```

This is the current error I am getting:

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger MasterOpportunityTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: MasterOpportunityTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 'xxxxxxxxxx') is currently in trigger MasterOpportunityTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []: Class.ClassOpportunityHandler.addProductWhenStageIsPendingPayment: line 81, column 1

Comment: Take a look at your rollup summaries. [You should create related data in after events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding child records in a `before` trigger when there is a rollup summary field, you will experience this issue. Simply move the application of this logic to an `after` trigger. It's one of the reasons Salesforce's documentation on [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) states (bold emphasis mine):

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and **to affect changes in other records**, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the *after trigger* are read-only.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did as you suggested but now Im getting a PriceEntryBook field integrity exception. I tried hardcoding the PriceBBookEntry ids as well, but I couldn't figure out what is causing this.

Comment: @Marc Well, it sounds like you resolved this issue at play here and now you have a new question.

Comment: ok sure I ll mark this question as closed then